# C finding image detail in tiff file without libtiff

Tags: c, tiff

I need help about tiff files. I need to resolve tags and return user image details (such as imageWidth, imageHeight, orientation etc.) without using any special library. With [this](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm) and [this](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html) I resolved header and found first IFD, but I couldn't understand finding tag and next  inside a single IFD.

for example, documentation says,

```
Offset   -  2+x*12    
Datatype - Tag structure
Value    - Tag data
```

but there is not any information about `x`. OR it says 2+(number of tags in IFD)*12 for next IFD offset, but the result is out of range.

In conclusion, I want to know how to find tags address and get their data, and find next IFD.

Comment: Did you look at the TIFF documentation? It pretty clearly explains the byte layout under section 2: http://partners.adobe.com/asn/developer/PDFS/TN/TIFF6.pdf

Comment: thank you so much, this documentation helped a lot